How to generate OTP instead of link to confirm email or reset password in ASP.NET Core 6 or 7 MVC using Identity
In my ASP.NET Core project, I've added authentication using ASP.NET Core Identity. I've also added MailKit and Mimekit in order to send authentication emails.
These are working fine but they send a link if I want to confirm my email or reset my password. But I want to generate OTP and send that via email to confirm email, reset password or any other section.
How can I do that? Can anyone help me?

You could refer to the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-7.0 as it is officially supported.

I don't want to add MFA/2FA. I exactly need how to generate OTP then bind it with the user id send it to mail and check it. Can you help me?
